# C# drawing on picturebox, not persistent

Tags: c#, bitmap, paint, picturebox

I have a List<> object, "imagelist", that contains the paths of many images such as .png's. Now, with the following code:

```
private void paint_picture(PictureBox picture, string pathofpic)
    {
        Graphics g = picture.CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap drawnpic = null;
        if (imagelist.ContainsKey(picture.Name))
        {
            drawnpic = new Bitmap(pathofpic);
            g.DrawImage(drawnpic, 0, 0, picture.Size.Width, picture.Size.Height);
            imagelist[picture.Name] = pathofpic;
        }
        drawnpic.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

I call this every time the card's image is changed, but I can't seem to make the image persist on the picturebox, when I drag the picturebox across the form (for example, over other pictureboxes). The click and drag code is just moving the picturebox with the mouse, not really relevant.

I've tried invalidating the form when I de-select the image, but it doesn't do anything.

Is there something I'm missing? Screenshot below, I dragged one image around the form and it overwrote the other images it moved across:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That’s how painting works – you have to handle its `Paint` event and keep painting the same thing each time it needs repainting.

What you can do is draw on top of your original image:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(picture.Image);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
    using (Bitmap drawnpic = new Bitmap(pathofpic)) {
        g.DrawImage(drawnpic, 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
    }
}

picture.Image = b;
```

Then you’d save the original image somewhere and probably use it instead of `picture.Image` in the `new Bitmap` line.

And `PascalCase` for method names, please. ;)

Comment: I can't use the image or backgroundimage properties of the picturebox, because it uses too much memory - I need to draw an image to an empty picturebox and have it stay persistent somehow. Is this not possible?

Comment: @Codefun64: No, it’s not. You have to keep it *somewhere*. Also, are your images perhaps a lot bigger than the picture box?

Comment: A bit, but that's not why I'm worried about memory usage. I'm creating possibly thousands of pictureboxes, I need a way to display images in them (possibly all unique images, not the same image as shown in my original question), and have them remain persistent.